# Android custom button generic click handler

Tags: android, android-button, android-custom-view, buttonclick

i'm trying to implement a custom button which allows me to execute a standard set of actions when the button is clicked (such as writing a log) plus executing the assigned click listener specific for every instance of the button. IS that possibile?

Many thanks

Comment: This sounds like standard button actions.  What you describe is standard button functionality and works in Android.  Give more details.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is the following: i have a class which extends Button. I use this button class all around the application, so it's used several times. The application is used in a business enviroment, and when a user reports a problem we take him to investigate the problem. So in order to have a trace of the user activity , i'd like to write a log every time the user clicks a button (i have function which get the name of a resource given it's id). So the need is to don't write the log on every click listener, but have this logic in the button it self.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution found, in this way for every instance of the button i can do a standard set of actions (in this case it's just writing a log) before executing the specified click listener

```
@Override
    public void setOnClickListener(final OnClickListener l) {

        super.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LogHelper.WriteLogInfo("click");
                l.onClick(v);

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Implement OnClickListener for your Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

Add click listener for all the views like this :

```
boldButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bold);
boldButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then Override OnClick event common for all the views :

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bold:
            // Do Something                  
            break;

        case R.id.italic:
            // Do Something
            break;

        case R.id.underline:
            // Do Something
            break;

        case R.id.reset:
            // Do Something
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i can't do this because the button is used hundred of times